# JavaScript code for counting the words input into an input box

Tags: javascript

I am supposed to write a function which can count the words in the text area but my code count only the first word, you can see the code here:

[link to my code](https://jsfiddle.net/diananova/kjp1gm6n/2/)

```
var myTextareaElement = document.getElementById("myWordsToCount");
myTextareaElement.onkeyup = function wordcount(wor){
  var myTextareaElement =document.getElementById("myWordsToCount").value;
  var haveByNow = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < wordcount.length; i++)
    if (wor[i] === " ") {
      haveByNow = +1;
    }
  haveByNow += 1;
  document.getElementById("wordcount").innerHTML = haveByNow;
}
```

Comment: Btw, this question has [been asked many times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+word+count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not splitting on empty character that textarea value and get arraylength:
 Check the **snippet below**

```js
var myTextareaElement = document.getElementById("myWordsToCount");
myTextareaElement.onkeyup = function wordcount(wor) {

  var myText = this.value.trim();
  var wordsArray = myText.split(/\s+/g);
  var words = wordsArray.length;


  document.getElementById("wordcount").innerHTML = words;
};
```

```html
<textarea id="myWordsToCount"></textarea>

<span id="wordcount"></span>
```

Comment: You should `trim` the value first; right now `"ab ce "` counts __3__.

Comment: To followup on @Mathletics comment: you could also split on a whitespace regex: `var wordsArray = myText.split(/\s+/g);`

Comment: @Mathletics thanks for the heads up, don't know how I passed over that.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
haveByNow = +1;
```

...is not the same as:

```
haveByNow += 1;
```

The former sets `haveByNow` to `1`, the other increments. This is why you'd be seeing a result of `1` every time.

Another problem is this expression in your `for` loop:

```
wordcount.length
```

`wordcount` is the name of your function, and `wordcount.length` is the number of parameters of that function, which is not going to be what you want. `myTextareaElement`, which is the value of the input is what you want to get the length of:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myTextareaElement.length; i++) ...
```

Though as @itsgoingdown points out, there are better ways to get a word count.

Comment: A function's [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) property is the number of formal parameters the function declares, not the number of source code characters in its body.

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos and errors, see working code:

```js
var myTextareaElement = document.getElementById("myWordsToCount");

myTextareaElement.onkeyup = function wordcount(wor){
    var words = myTextareaElement.value;
    var haveByNow = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i] == " ") {
            haveByNow += 1;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("wordcount").innerHTML = haveByNow;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myWordsToCount" rows="5" cols="60"></textarea><br>
The wordcount is: <span id="wordcount"></span><br>
```